# Formal completion of the normal bundle

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, ac.commutative-algebra

Let me for simplicity start with affine case. If $X=\operatorname{Spec}(A)$ is an affine variety $Z \subset X$ is a closed affine subvariety $Z=\operatorname{Spec}(A/I)$. What conditions are sufficient to say that completion of the (total space of) normal bundle $N_{Z/X}$ along zero section is isomorphic to the completion of $X$ along $Z$?

Comment: Non-example: $Z$ a cusp in a curve $X$. Then the normal bundle and its completion are nonreduced, but the completion in $X$ is reduced. (So whatever condition you use must rule that out.)

Comment: Yes, in fact I'm ready to assume that $X$ and $Z$ are smooth.

Comment: Suppose for a moment that the ideal $Z$ is generated by an element, which is not a zero divisor and that $Z$ is smooth over the base field. Then Lemma 3.6 in 'Differential algebra - a scheme theory approach' by H. Gillet will prove that the answer is yes. Note that the isomorphism depends on the choice of a derivation. The general case (if $Z$ is smooth) should be provable along the same lines. For a general schematic regular immersion, I think this still works, if you can produce the relevant derivations (my guess is: if the normal bundle is trivial).

Comment: PS *The above is only valid in char. 0* because it uses the exponential map.

Comment: It's true if $X$ is a bundle over $Z$. Then the completion is a bundle, and the automorphism group of the bundle is an extension of $GL_n$ by a unipotent group. The bundle is classified by cohomology of this group. $GL_n$ cohomology is just a vector bundle, the normal bundle. Unipotent cohomology on an affine variety is trivial, so it's just the completion of the normal bundle.

Comment: @Will Savin: what do you mean by 'the completion is a bundle' ?

Comment: @Will Savin: PS: The OP considers the formalisation of $Z$ inside $N_{Z/X}$, not the formalisation of $N_{Z/X}$ (unless I have been completely mislead).

Comment: I mean the completion is locally isomorphic to a product of Z with the completion of a point inside affine space.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The formal completion of $X$ along $Z$ is always isomorphic to that of the normal bundle $N_{Z \subset X}$ along its zero section if $X= \mathrm{Spec}(A)$ and $Z = \mathrm{Spec}(A/I)$ are smooth and affine over some base $k$. If the affineness or smoothness assumption is dropped, it is easy to give counterexamples.

---

It's easier to work in the world of algebra, so I will show that there exists an isomorphism of $k$-algebras

$$\widehat{\mathrm{Sym}}_{A/I}(I/I^2) \to \widehat{A}$$

compatible with the projection down to $A/I$. Here $\widehat{A}$ is the $I$-adic completion of $A$, and $\widehat{\mathrm{Sym}}_{A/I}(I/I^2)$ is the completion of the symmetric algebra $\mathrm{Sym}_{A/I}(I/I^2)$ along the augmentation ideal.

By the infinitesimal criterion for smoothness, one can find a compatible system of $k$-algebra maps $\epsilon_n:A/I \to A/I^n$ lifting the projection $A/I^n \to A/I$. In the limit, we obtain a $k$-algebra map $\epsilon:A/I \to \widehat{A}$ lifting the projection $\widehat{A} \to A/I$. Using $\epsilon$, we view $\widehat{A}$ and each quotient $A/I^n$ as $A/I$-algebras.

Now the $A/I$-module $I/I^2$ is a projective module as $X$ and $Z$ are smooth. There is an obvious $A/I$-module map $I/I^2 \to A/I^2 \simeq \widehat{A}/I\widehat{A}^2$. By projectivity, one can find an $A/I$-module map $I/I^2 \to \widehat{A}$ lifting the previous one. By the universal property of the symmetric algebra, this extends to an $A/I$-algebra map $\mathrm{Sym}_{A/I}(I/I^2) \to \widehat{A}$. As both sides are augmented over $A/I$, this naturally extends to an $A/I$-algebra map $\widehat{\mathrm{Sym}}_{A/I}(I/I^2) \to \widehat{A}$; by filtering both sides suitably, one can check that this is an isomorphism.

Comment: I think you need to complete the symmetric algebra along the augmentation ideal to get the iso. of $k$-algebras you mention.

Answer (score 2):

This is exactly the same answer as that of anonymous (which was 12 minutes earlier). So please read that one.

Suppose that $R$ is a ring and that $X$ is a scheme over $R$. I think the question is whether there exists an $R$-algebra ismorphism
$$
A^\wedge \cong A/I[[I/I^2]]
$$
where the left hand side is the $I$-adic completion of $A$ and the right hand side is completion of the symmetric algebra on $I/I^2$.

Let's assume for simplicity that $I$ is finitely generated, so that we know that $A^\wedge$ is complete.

To get such an isomorphism, the first thing we want is section $\sigma : A/I \to A^\wedge$ to the canonical map $A^\wedge \to A/I$. Besides $\sigma$ we want a map $\tau : I/I^2 \to A^\wedge$ which is $A/I$-linear (here we are using $\sigma$), maps into the kernel $IA^\wedge$ of the canonical map $A^\wedge \to A/I$ and then induces an isomorphism $I/I^2 \to IA^\wedge/I^2A^\wedge$. Given $\sigma$ and $\tau$ we can at least define an $R$-algebra map
$$
A/I[[I/I^2]] \longrightarrow A^\wedge
$$
In general the existence of $\sigma$ and $\tau$ is not good enough to imply that this map is an isomorphism. But if you assume for example that $I$ is a quasi-regular ideal then it is an isomorphism (follows more or less immediately from the definition of quasi-regular ideals).

If both $A$ and $A/I$ are smooth over $R$, then $\sigma$ and $\tau$ exist and the resulting map is an isomorphism. The existence of $\sigma$ for example follows because $A/I$ is formally smooth over $R$, hence we can successively lift the map $\text{id} : A/I \to A/I$ to $A/I \to A/I^n$ and taking the limit gives $\sigma$. Then existence of $\tau$ comes from the fact that in this case the module $I/I^2$ is a finite projective $A/I$-module, hence there are no obstructions to lifting the linear map $I/I^2 \to A/I^2$ to $I/I^2 \to A/I^n$ and we can take the limit. Finally, the ideal defining a closed immersion of schemes smooth over $R$ is a regular ideal, see for example the more general [Lemma Tag 067T](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/067T).

If you are unfamiliar with some of the terms used above please try using the [search function](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/search) of the Stacks project to find their definitions. Moreover, some of the statements used above about completions of rings aren't entirely trivial and can be found there as well.

Comment: Or see EGA $0_{\rm{IV}}$ 19.5.4 with some extra topological pizzazz (that can be ignored, using discrete topologies). They use the older technique of extensive cross-referencing to substitute for the lack of search functions in physical books. :)

Comment: Of course it would be trivial to set up such a search function for an online version of EGA, but that would probably run into legal issues having to do with copyright.