# On formal completions of normal bundles in the non-affine case

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, formal-schemes

According to this [post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/159762/formal-completion-of-the-normal-bundle). In the affine case the formal completion of $A$ along an ideal $I$ coincides with the formal is isomorphic to the completion of the normal bundle along its zero section. I was wondering can something like this happen in non-affine case (projective varieties), where let's say the closed subvariety is some ample divisor? (I'd appreciate any interesting examples if it is possible)
List of questions:

1. Does any smooth proejctive variety $X$ admit a smooth ample divisor $Y$ such that completion of $X$ along $Y$ coincides with the completion of normal bundle of $Y$ along its zero section?
2. If not what interesting examples are there that are not trivial (for example when both $X$ and $Y$ are projective spaces.)

As mentioned in the comment section [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/138690/are-formal-completions-along-a-subvariety-only-dependent-on-the-normal-bundle) a necessary and sufficient.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are formal completions along a subvariety only dependent on the normal bundle?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/138690/are-formal-completions-along-a-subvariety-only-dependent-on-the-normal-bundle)

Comment: It is very close but it doesn't provide any examples for the situation I'm asking. Jason Starr also provides an if and only if condition which I don't quite understand it, if someone can expand it in more details, that'd be also helpful.